# Changing color of button text and state

Tags: swift

I need to change the color of my button's text.
I also need to change the state to Disabled after the user presses it.

I have no idea how to do this. I've been looking things up for a while but they're all either in objective C or I can't understand it (usually help docs, they're stupid.).

Comment: What am I supposed to put then? I need to know what to write.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To change color of text

```
button.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

To change state, on button press add following -

```
button.enabled = true
```

IBAction method should be like -

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton!) {
    sender.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you. I get an error for changing the state, though. (AnyObject) -> () Does not have a member named enabled. It also does this for titleLabel.

Comment: Please change no to false. My mistake, still living in Objective-C days

Comment: Is your button on storyboard or programmatically created. enabled works in my case. Change it to false, not true.

Comment: It's on my storyboard, but I linked it into the ViewController.

Comment: Probably it's optional, do this -  button!.enabled = false

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm doing this inside of a button in ViewController.swift.

Comment: Ohh, are you doing it in inside IBAction method?

Comment: Yeah. I'm using it in there.

Comment: Your IBAction should be like                                                 @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton!) {
        
        sender.enabled = false
        
  }

Answer (score 83):

In swift you change color for a specific State with the setTitleColor method.

In you case it will be :

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Swift 5 Update:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Comment: Accepted answer didn't change my button text colour. This answer worked for me.

Comment: Thank so much for sharing this, miner change I did was `button.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: This solution worked for me but I'm wondering why setting the color like `button.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
` doesn't do the trick. Is it because the view was already rendered?

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3**

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Note that;

- grayColor has been renamed to gray
- Normal is now normal (lowercase)

You have to set the text colour for the specific button state.

Answer (score 5):

For **Swift3**, try below code :

```
 @IBAction func butnClicked(sender : UIButton) {
     sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
     sender.isEnabled = false
 }
```

Set **`Enabled`** and text color from story board.

[image]