# change the color of the button on click and off click

Tags: ios, swift3, ibaction

[image]

Every time the user click any one of the above  buttons a new view controller is displaying,i have a green colored icon and a black colored icon as well. the functionality I need is that the click on any of these buttons will make the others black and the clicked one to be cyan color. I am not able to know how do I do this. does the buttons have any delegates to be called or what. please suggest me the right method.

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: i followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170421/changing-color-of-button-text-and-state.

Comment: Put the actual code in the question, not a link to the answer you followed.

Comment: You can configure the different states of a `UIButton` in the storyboard.  A quick Google search will give you plenty of information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Set selected Image and deselected Image in `Attribute Inspector`.

[image][image]

Then set below property to the `UIButton`.

```
selectedButton.isSelected = true
normalButton.isSelected = false
```