# UIButton subclass change tittle color without setTitleColor(_ , for state:) [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, swift5

How can I change the `UIButton` `TitleLabel` text color in a subclass **without** using `func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControl.State)`? `self.titleLabel!.textColor = .yellow` does not work (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25170523/8150874)).

---

*What I'm trying to do:*

Currently I'm working in a `UIButton` subclass, I'm handling the behaviour of the various `setSomethingColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControl.State)` with overrides and `didSet` over `isSelected`, `isHighlighted`... Setting the color properties of the various elements by my self.

I can change the background color `self.backgroundColor = .red`, the tint color `self.tintColor = .green` but **I cannot change the text color** with `self.titleLabel!.textColor = .yellow`, which seems is the correct way to set the color for a `UILabel`...

Is the only possible way to do it with `func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControl.State)`? Am I missing something?

*Thank you for your help.*

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel)

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor(*:for:) and setTitleShadowColor(*:for:)
>   methods of this class to make those changes. To set the actual text of
>   the label, use setTitle(_:for:) (button.titleLabel.text does not let
>   you set the text). The titleLabel property returns a value even if the
>   button has not been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil
>   for system buttons.

Comment: So there is no way to do it without using those functions?

Comment: other ways are not Apple recommended

Comment: I'll leave the question unanswered to see if someone found another way. Thank you very much!